# angular & ngrx: problems during upgrading to version8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

My current project is using angular/ngrx 7, and I'm planing to upgrade to latest version 8.

My project is an angular library with a demo app, which is a typical style in the angular field.

I following some posts online about related topics to upgrade my project:

upgrade Angular

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force
```

this step I have to add `--force` parameter to force the upgrade.

upgrade Ngrx

```
ng update @ngrx/store
```

in this step I get many warning message similar to the following one:

```
NgRx 8 Migration: Unable to run the schematics to rename \`META_REDUCERS\` to \`USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS\`
            in file '/projects/xxx/src/lib/xxx.module.ts'.

            For more info see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8#meta_reducers-token.
```

what's this. I can't find  `META_REDUCERS` in my code.

secondly, when i try to build my library i get the following error and failed to start:

[image]

Comment: Did you already follow the link they give ? Also add the code where you have that error it will easy for everyone to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore this message, it shouldn't be printed out when you're not using the `META_REDUCERS` token.